# Зависает изображение в Linux Mint

Tags: linux, экран, видеокарта

После установки Linux Ubuntu 18.04 спустя несколько дней возникла проблема с зависанием изображения на мониторе. При этом звук продолжает работать без каких-либо искажений. После зависания экран начинает моргать и с каждым морганием изображение начинает искажаться по-новому. Вместо картинки появляется рябь на экране, похожая на помехи в телевизоре который отключен от антены. Экран делится на большие квадраты и курсор мыши превращается в один из таких квадратов. Я попробовал поставить Linux Mint. После установки стало чуть лучше. Проблема полностью не исчезла, но при искажении изображения экран начинает моргать и иногда помехи проходят и становится возможным продолжать работу. Но все же бывает что экран не перестаёт моргать и помогает только принудительное выключение компьютера. В линуксе новичек, поэтому не знаю варианты лечения данной ситуации. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема. В ОС Windows10 всё работает хорошо. Утилита lspci возвращает данное сообщение: "01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470]". Спасибо.

Comment: Обновляйте BIOS, ядро OS, компьютер...

Answer (score 0):

Цитата - "Начал пробы с 64-bit версии Linux Mint 19.1, затем была 32-bit LM 19.1. Продолжил ставить свежие LM, но уже на Debian: LMDE 3 "Cindy" Cinnamon (64-bit) - моргание дисплея присутствовало на всех, на LMDE 3 "Cindy" мигало пореже. Убедившись, что свежие версии LM конфликтуют с моим железом/драйверами перешел к LM с более старыми версиями ядра. По наводке собрата по несчастью установил самую старую версию Linux Mint 17 (64-bit), которая будет поддерживаться до апреля 2019 года - на ней моргание отсутствовало! Но отсутствовал и звук, потому с радостью установил последнюю версию из 17-х: Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa MATE (64-bit). ФИНАЛ - ВСЁ (нужное) РАБОТАЕТ. Моргание дисплея отсутствует, звук присутствует."

Источник - https://xn--h1aafched3ame.xn--p1ai/forum/miganie-displeja-monitora-v-ustanovlennoi-os-linux-mint-19-xfce-64-bit.html#post_87